# Xcode continous integration bot how to build multiple targets and get multiple ipas

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ipa, build-server

I have an enterprise app that builds to a large number of targets (one per customer). I am now trying to configure continous integration for it but am a little confused about how it's supposed to work.

If I have a bot building a scheme containing 1 target, then it produces an IPA but configuring 30 or so schemes and the same number of bots seems an inefficient way of doing things. Instead I tried making a single continous integration scheme containing all 30 targets, but when the bot builds that it doesn't produce an IPA - instead I get a 'Generic xcode archive'.

Where do I go from here? Should I be going down the route of lots of schemes and bots or is there a way to get lots of IPAs out of a bot with multiple targets?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use TeamCity, it is open source and you can setup on your own server or use the hosted solution.